# Running UITableView refresh function automatically and asynchronously when view loads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I have the following refresh function

```
func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

    self.newsArray = [NewsItem]()
    self.newslists = [[NewsItem]]()
    self.getNewsFromServer()
    self.getNewsFromCoreData()
    self.tViewNews.reloadData()

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

It works perfectly, just the way I want it, and I can refresh as many times as I want.

Is there any way I can run this refresh function automatically in `viewDidLoad()` directly after the code where I populate from Core Data.

(Preferably working completely in the background, no loading sign)

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("Getting news from Core Data")
    getNewsFromCoreData()

    // refreshing asynchronously  
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,  0), {

        self.newsArray = [NewsItem]()
        self.newslists = [[NewsItem]]()
        self.getNewsFromServer()
        self.getNewsFromCoreData()


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.tViewNews.reloadData()

            });
        })
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,  0), {

        refresh()
```

Comment: Would you be more specific about your problem and what you've already tried to solve it?

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? Are you trying to load your data in the background, or refreshing the UITableView in the background?

Comment: It is still unclear what you want us to do for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn about multi-thread/background processing in iOS, I would recommend you this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

It perfectly explains the GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) and how to apply it.